# How to add in every link (a href) tag a rel attribute with the help of php?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, image, tags

I have a variable $mydata (**my code is in php**) which includes text and some pictures. Every picture included is in this form :

```
<img src="mypicture.jpg" alt="lala" title="lala" border="0" />
```

This variable $mydata which has text and images after is inserted into my database (mysql).

What i want to do is, with some way to add to every and each one of the link images into the a href tag, before the img tag, one more attribute and this is rel="lightbox" so that lightbox effect with be applied in all of my images, such as :

```
<a href="mypicture_fullsize.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="mypicture.jpg" rel="lightbox" alt="lala" title="lala" border="0" /></a>
```

How to make this in php, can you help me please ?

I guess may we have to use some kind of regular expression in order to implement that but my knowledge of regular expressions is not so advance.. can you help me please ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wAp5tvNc

Comment: Please show your PHP in the question

Answer (score 3):

```
$pat = <<<pattern
~(<a href="[^"]+")(><img src="[^"]+" alt="[^"]+" title="[^"]+" border="[^"]+" /></a>)~
pattern;
$html = preg_replace($pat, "\\1 rel=\"lightbox\"\\2", $html);
```

Comment: am sorry ...i did a mistake i wanted to add rel="lightbox" into the <a href=""></a> tag with is out of img tag <a href="" rel=""><img src="mypicture.jpg" alt="lala" title="lala" border="0" /></a> how to apply it on a href so ?

Comment: almost the same:
 $pat = '~(<a href="[^"]+")(>)~'; $html = preg_replace($pat, "\\1 rel=\"lightbox\" \\2", $html);

Comment: Both of your answers where correct **Thank You both** Sharanya Dutta and Michael Livach so much for helping me with my problem, Thanks again !!

Answer (score 1):

If all the pictures in $mydata do not have the "rel" attribute, then solution is simple

```
$mydata = str_replace('<img ', '<img rel="lightbox"', $mydata);
```

In other cases, only if ">" character does not appear in attribute values​​, this code works

```
function rel_adder( $matches ) {
    if ( strpos($matches[0], 'rel=') === false ) {
        return $matches[1].'rel="lightbox" '. $matches[2];
    } else {
        return $matches[0];
    }
}
$mydata = preg_replace_callback('#(<img )([^>]+)>#i', "rel_adder", $mydata);
```

Comment: Both of your asnwers where correct **Thank You both** Sharanya Dutta and Michael Livach so much for helping me with my problem, Thanks again !