# How to add rel="lightbox" only to links which are including an image and not the rest of the links?

Tags: php, html, regex, image, tags

Lets say that (in php) we have a variable which has text, links and images :

```
<a href="myimage_big"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="pic" title="pic" border="0" /></a>
```

and we want to add to every a href tag the rel="light" as follow :

```
<a rel="lightbox" href="myimage_big"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="pic" title="pic" border="0" /></a>
```

If the name of the variable is lets say **$mydata** then with str_replace we can do as follow to solve our problem :

```
$mydata = str_replace('<img ', '<img rel="lightbox"', $mydata);
```

Till here is all right, but what about the rest of the a href links that are not including any photo :

par example,

```
<a href="link1.php">link_no1</a>
<a href="link2.php">link_no2</a>
```

etc ? To this kind of links that are not including any image but text then with our str_replace code will also have a rel="lightbox" attribute that is not correct and i dont want :

```
<a rel="lightbox" href="link1.php">link_no1</a>
```

So how we can apply the rel="lightbox" **only** to the links that are including some image and to those links that are not including any image to dont set the rel="lightbox" attribute ..!?

Comment: Not sure at all what you're asking - can you make your examples clearer?

Comment: Is everything in one big string, or do you have a different string for each link?

Comment: Hello, by using the str_replace as i show before i can add to every : <a href=""><img src="" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a> a rel="lighbox" tag like <a rel="lightbox" href=""><img... /></a> BUT then the problem is that a rel="lightbox" is applied to the links that are not including any images too like <a rel="lightbox" href="">sometext</a> and this i dont want, how to solve this so ?

Comment: Barmar all text,links and images are into one variable called $mydata

Comment: Let me be more clear if i can, the issue is : How can we add rel="lightbox" only to every <a href=""><img.. /></a> and NOT to <a href="">Sometext</a>  ..?? Maybe with the use of some regex or how ?

Comment: You should use an HTML DOM parser, not string replacement.

Comment: I thought that is easier to use string replacement and combine it with some regex (note my knowledge of regex is really poor). What you mean about HTML DOM i have no idea about it .. ?

Comment: I think you’ve already asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763133/how-to-add-in-every-link-a-href-tag-a-rel-attribute-with-the-help-of-php/20763185). Are you not satisfied with the two answers you’ve received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this regex solve the problem?

```
$str = '<a href="myimage_big"><img src="myimage.jpg" /></a>';

$str = preg_replace('~<a(?=[^>]+>\s*<img)~','<a rel="lightbox"',$str);

echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

Using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check, if the `<a ...>` is followed by `<img`

Comment: Yes this just solved my problem, Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great, you welcome! And merry Xmas :-)

Comment: Merry Xmass n' Happy New Year Jonny 5 ! Peace, health, love, happiness, freedom and good luck for everybody :)

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use a regular expression ...

```
$html = preg_replace('/(?<=<a)(?=[^>]*>[^<]*<img)/', ' rel="lightbox"', $html);
```

Although, I would consider using [**DOM**](http://www.php.net/book.dom) and **XPath** ...

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <a href="myimage_big"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="pic" title="pic" border="0" /></a>
     <a href="link1.php">link_no1</a>
     <a href="link2.php">link_no2</a>
     <a href="image.jpg"><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query('//a//img');

foreach($links as $link) { 
   $link->parentNode->setAttribute('rel', 'lightbox');
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks but i must read more about this method and DOM, i will:) But please tell me why you are advising me in this specific case to stay away from regex ?

Comment: Because you should not use regular expression to try and parse any kind of HTML, XML, ... tags. It sometimes gets more complicated than you think.

Comment: Yes maybe my knowledge of regex still is poor but in this case finally the solution that Jonny 5 gave it was simple not ? I thought that you told me not to use regex for security reasons but anyway thanks again