# Adding link tags and rel="lightbox" around images Regex

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress

How can i change this example when i just got the `<image>` tag and i want to add link tags around them and the rel lightbox attribute as well?
i cant figure it out. I'm just not good with regular expressions at all.

the example

```
$pattern ="/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
$replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 rel="lightbox" title="'.$post->post_title.'"$6>';
```

So in my case i have `<img src="...." class="...." alt=".....">`

and i need `<a href="....." rel="lightbox" title="....."><img src="...." class="...." alt="....."></a>`
How would i change this?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you  mean a $_POST request ? If yes, what is the variable that you send trough the form that tells if you ahve lightbox or not in the image ?

Comment: Oh it's a wordpress I see what you mean, what I suggest you is to find what's in your $post variable by doing: print_r($post). Then, it should return you the structure of your posts object. You will then be able to see what is the variable that tells if it is an image and if it uses lightbox

Comment: thanks guys - i recently found a funtion who can do this  but i cant get the regex working right - please view my edits. thanks for your help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20767976/2206004

Comment: Are you sure the attributes will always follow in this same order? In `<img>`, first is `src`, then `class`, then `alt`?

Comment: yes its should be always the same order

Comment: @jimmy: Is that what you want? https://regex101.com/r/sM2qR6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you exactly want to do here, but I would utilize **DOM** for this task instead.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <img src="www.foo.com/1.gif" class="foo" alt="...">
     <img src="www.bar.com/1.jpg" class="bar" alt="...">
     <img src="example.com/2.jpg" class="example" alt="...">   
');

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
   $link = $node->ownerDocument->createElement('a');

   $a = $node->parentNode->insertBefore($link, $node);

   $a->setAttribute('href', $node->getAttribute('src'));
   $a->setAttribute('rel', 'lightbox');
   $a->setAttribute('title', 'some title');

   $a->appendChild($node);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="www.foo.com/1.gif" rel="lightbox" title="some title"><img src="www.foo.com/1.gif" class="foo" alt="..."></a>
<a href="www.bar.com/1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="some title"><img src="www.bar.com/1.jpg" class="bar" alt="..."></a>
<a href="example.com/2.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="some title"><img src="example.com/2.jpg" class="example" alt="..."></a>
```